# Angular 2/4 : Services Get with params

Tags: angular, rest, typescript

I Have a restful services and I want to call this services with HTTP/GET services of Angular 4. But with the params in my services, I don't know the way than I can take for do it.

The Java Code :

```
@GET
@Path("/typeOfDemandByCode/{code}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getLabelByCode(@PathParam(value="code") String code) {
    return administrationsBusiness.getLabelByCode(code);
}
```

My service.ts (I use RequestOptions)

```
  getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode(code: string) {
     let myHeader = new Headers();
    myHeader.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let myParams = new URLSearchParams();
    myParams.set('code', code);
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeader, params: myParams });
    return this.http.get('/CCPDWebService/administration/typeOfDemandByCode', options)
      .map((response) => {
          return response.text() ? response.json() : [{}];
      }) 
  }
```

component.ts

```
 getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode(code : string) {
    return this.adminService.getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode(code).subscribe(
      labelTypeOfDemand => {
        this.labelTypeOfDemand = labelTypeOfDemand;
      });
  }

  saveFolder() {
       // Here I do a test for getting value 
      console.log(this.getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode("BGS"));
  }
```

But when I tried to get a value of my list with "params code" I got in this line inmy console:

```
Subscriber {closed: false, _parent: null, _parents: null, _subscriptions: Array(1), syncErrorValue: null, …}

 GET http://localhost:4200/CCPDWebService/administration/typeOfDemandByCode 404 (Not Found)
```

My JSON like :

```
 {
      "id": 9,
      "code": "BGS",
      "label": "TEST",
      "status": null
   },
      {
      "id": 7,
      "code": "PBA",
      "label": "TEST",
      "status": null
   },
      {
      "id": 8,
      "code": "KBA",
      "label": "TEST",
      "status": null
   }
```

Comment: Your Java says `/typeByCode/` and your typescript says `/typeOfDemandByCode`. Also the Java seems to want the code as part of the url, not as a query parameter.

Comment: Yes I am sorry It is an Error of typing .. but in my code Java and typeScript have the same name ... So the solution must be like :        `return this.http.get('/CCPDWebService/administration/typeOfDemandByCode/'+code+'')
      .map((response) => {
          return response.text() ? response.json() : [{}];
      }) `  ?

Comment: Your resource doesn't expect any URL search param. Just remove all the useless and incorrect header and url search param stuff, and use `return this.http.get(``/CCPDWebService/administration/typeOfDemandByCode/${code}``).map(resp => resp.json())`. Note that the Http service is basically deprecated. You should learn and use HttpClient. (with single backticks, but I can't format that correctly)

Comment: @JBNizet, you wanted ``this.http.get(`/CCPDWebService/administration/typeOfDemandB‌​yCode/${code}`).map‌​(resp => resp.json())`` double the outer backquotes and then you can include single ones inside.

Comment: Ok thx,, but how can definie a global variable for assign it to the result of this method ? I need to use the return value of this service and assign it to a global variable like : MyComponent.ts  `name : string; getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode(code : string){
  this.adminService.getLabelTypeOfDemandByCode(code).subscribe(
      labelByCode => {
        this.labelByCode = labelByCode;
       // Here I want to do it this.name = this.labelByCode and after use variable in an other method});
  }`